# CSV data loading as array of arrays; How to convert into object?

Tags: javascript

I was wanting to see if there is a relatively simple method for doing this as I can use the following:

```
var arr = [ "Client", "ActType", "CallRepType"];
var arr2 = [ "ECF", "Meeting", "Call Report"]
var myobj = arr2.map(value => ({'Client': arr2[0], 'ActType': arr2[1], 'CallRepType': arr2[2]}));
```

But I get the same correct object 3 times in a row...I simply want a single object returned that looks like:

```
{Client: 'ECF', ActType: 'Meeting', CallRepType: 'Call Report'}
```

I know I can loop through both `arrays` but I was hoping to get a solution using `map`, reduce or taking advantage of spread in `javascript`...

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: ^ There's also no such thing as an ATM machine or a PIN number, but people still claim to use both ;)

Comment: And reflect ineptitude in the process of doing so :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster solution that uses `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
var arr = [ "Client", "ActType", "CallRepType"];
var arr2 = [ "ECF", "Meeting", "Call Report"]
var result = {};
arr.forEach((el, i) => { result[el] = arr2[i]; });

console.log(result);
```

Array.prototype.forEach()`

Comment: very nice! Works great

Answer (score 2):

This a solution that uses [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the object:

```js
const arr = [ "Client", "ActType", "CallRepType"];
const arr2 = [ "ECF", "Meeting", "Call Report"]
const myobj = arr.reduce((r, key, i) => {
  r[key] = arr2[i];
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(myobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and do it:

```js
var arr = [ "Client", "ActType", "CallRepType"];
var arr2 = [ "ECF", "Meeting", "Call Report"];
var len = arr.length;
var myObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var myObject = {};
    myObj[arr[i]] = arr2[i]
   // myObj.push = myObject;
}

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: I know about looping through the arrays, I wanted to learn how to utilize built in methods to do it

Comment: @MattE Ok, added one more example

Comment: Neither method produces the OP's desired output, an object with the members `{Client: 'ECF', ActType: 'Meeting', CallRepType: 'Call Report'}` _not_ an array of objects each with one member.

Comment: @StephenP My bad. Removed it.